# ArchUnit ignoreDependency for classes rule

Tags: java, junit5, archunit

In my [project](https://github.com/tfassbender/onnessium) I'm using some simple `ArchRule` test to ensure that there are no unwanted dependencies between packages. Most of them work fine, but the following test leads to a problem ([test source on github](https://github.com/tfassbender/onnessium/blob/master/core/test/net/jfabricationgames/onnessium/archunit/NetworkDependencyRules.java)):

```
@ArchTest
private final ArchRule networkPackagesMustNotDependOnOtherPackagesOutsideNetwork = classes().that() //
            .resideInAPackage("..onnessium.network.shared..") //
            .should().onlyDependOnClassesThat() //
            .resideInAnyPackage("..onnessium.network..", "java..", "com.esotericsoftware.kryo..", "com.esotericsoftware.kryonet..");
```

This rule finds a violation in the class `PasswordEncryptor` ([source on github](https://github.com/tfassbender/onnessium/blob/master/core/src/net/jfabricationgames/onnessium/network/shared/PasswordEncryptor.java)):

```
public class PasswordEncryptor {
    
    private static final char[] ENCRYPTION_KEY = "password".charArray();

    // ...
}
```

The cause of the violation is the `char[]`. The violation says:

> Field <...PasswordEncryptor.ENCRYPTION_KEY> has type <[C> in (PasswordEncryptor.java:0)

I found [this issue](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/issues/887) on GitHub that explains how to solve this kind of problem for tests that are based on `Architectures.layeredArchitecture()`, but I couldn't figure out how to do something similar when using a `classes()...` rule.

So **my question is**: is there something similar to `ignoreDependency` (like described in [this issue](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/issues/887)) for tests that use `classes().that()...` instead of a layered architecture? Or should I change the tests to use `Architecture.layeredArchitecture()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArchUnit (as of the current version 0.23.1) assigns `char[]` to the empty package `""` (probably because `char[].class.getPackage() == null`).
(Side note: I just realized that `char[].class.getPackageName()`, available with JRE ≥9, actually returns `"java.lang"`... )

If you want to allow for primitives and arrays of primitives, you can simply allow for the empty package:

```java
@ArchTest
private final ArchRule networkPackagesMustNotDependOnOtherPackagesOutsideNetwork = classes().that() //
    .resideInAPackage("..onnessium.network.shared..") //
    .should().onlyDependOnClassesThat() //
    .resideInAnyPackage(ArchUnitUtils.addAllLibraryPackages("..onnessium.network.."
        // <fix> <!-- just 3 characters  -->
        , ""
        // </fix>
    ));
```

Comment: FYI: ArchUnit 1.0 will [assign primitives to the `java.lang` package](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/commit/ee90e389c5d4052dc6d4914e2c0f44e7a317a03d).